# Query inside @AuraEnabled is not able to fetch parent

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I tried to get the contact name and parent Account from a query `SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact` but Account.Name returns only id not the name of the parent account. 
My code below
Component

```
<aura:component controller="ContactsController">
<aura:attribute name="contacts" type="List" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--fixed-layout">
     <thead>
          <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact Name">Contact Name</div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div></th>                    
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
             <tr>
                <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Name}">{!contact.Name}</div></td>
                <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!contact.Account.name}">{!contact.Account.name}</div></td>                     
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>

</table>
</aura:component>
```

controller

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {      
    // Fetch the Contact list from the Apex controller   
    helper.getContactList(component);
}
})
```

helper

```
({
  getContactList: function(component) {
        var actions = component.get('c.getContacts');

        console.log('action '+ actions);
        actions.setCallback(this, function(response) {                
            component.set('v.contacts', response.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(actions);
  }
  })
```

Server controller

```
public class ContactsController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getContacts(){
    List<Contact> cLsit = new List<Contact>();
        cLsit = [SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact];
    system.debug('cLsit ' + cLsit);
    return cLsit;
} }
```

In server side controller debug itself i checked the result contains Account Id instead of Account Name. Do any one have any idea what might be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print the JSON list returned from `getContacts()` method, Account name property is in camel case (i.e.: `Name`) whereas you're accessing it by all small characters (i.e. `name`).

Here is how your JSON looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Rose Gonzalez",
        "AccountId": "0016F00001rXwDdQAK",
        "Id": "0036F000022w3riQAA",
        "Account": {
            "Name": "Edge Communications",
            "Id": "0016F00001rXwDdQAK"
        }
    }
]
```

To resolve the issue replace:

```
{!contact.Account.name}
```

with:

```
{!contact.Account.Name}
```

Note: In lightning, as JavaScript is case sensitive and with returning data via SObject from server side, you'd not be sure on what casing would be returned; hence its a good practice to return data with wrapper classes.